# Muita dificuldade em montar um update com linq

Tags: c#, linq, reportviewer, linq-to-entities

Já fiz alguns updates com linq sem problema. mas da forma como está meu código, estou tendo dificuldade. Qual a regra:

1) Tenho uma tela onde eu faço algumas solicitações de relatórios. Logo eu posso ter n solicitações em andamento.

2) Essas solicitações, eu preencho alguns campos, exceto dois campo: `DT_GERACAO` e `BL_RELATORIO`. BL_RELATORIO deve conter um arquivo binário(campo LOB-Oracle), que é o relatório em si(Um array de bytes gerado na minha aplicação).

3) Aí quando eu chamar o relatório, ele dever pegar o primeiro registro que encontrar e popular esse dois campos `null`, onde a `DT_GERACAO` recebe `DateTime.Now()` e o `BL_RELATORIO` recebe o arquivo binário gerado, porém apenas um por vez, ou seja, cada vez que eu executar o relatório, ele busca na tabela em questão e vê se os dois campos citados estão `null` e então popula. A aplicação que gera o relatório, é uma aplicação console e não tenho nenhum contexto nela, apenas dataset. Veja o código abaixo do gerador de relatório.

```
public static void Emitir()
        {
            //Relatório com DataSource = ORACLE
            dsPlanoMedico.PLANO_MEDICODataTable dtPlanoMedico = new dsPlanoMedico.PLANO_MEDICODataTable();
            dsPlanoMedico.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIODataTable dtSolicRel = new dsPlanoMedico.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIODataTable();

            dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.PLANO_MEDICOTableAdapter adapt = new dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.PLANO_MEDICOTableAdapter();
            dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIOTableAdapter solic_adapt = new dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIOTableAdapter();

            adapt.Fill(dtPlanoMedico);
            solic_adapt.Fill(dtSolicRel);
            dtSolicRel.Where(p => p.DT_GERACAO == null && p.BL_RELATORIO == null).First();
            //dtPlanoMedico.Where(i => i.IND_REGULAMENTADO == "S");

            var dv = new System.Data.DataView(dtPlanoMedico);
            dv.RowFilter = "IND_REGULAMENTADO LIKE 'N' and TIPO_REGISTRO_ANS LIKE 'D'";
            //dv.RowFilter = "TIPO_REGISTRO_ANS LIKE 'D'";

            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsDados", dv);
            ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();

            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ReportBD.rdlc";
            //viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Regulamentado", "S"));
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;

            byte[] bytesPDF = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsPDF = new FileStream("c:\\Relatemp\\report.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            fsPDF.Write(bytesPDF, 0, bytesPDF.Length);
            fsPDF.Close();
            fsPDF.Dispose();

            byte[] bytesExcel = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsExcel = new FileStream("c:\\Relatemp\\report.xls", FileMode.Create);
            fsExcel.Write(bytesExcel, 0, bytesExcel.Length);
            fsExcel.Close();
            fsExcel.Dispose();

            byte[] bytesWord = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Word", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsWord = new FileStream("c:\\Relatemp\\report.doc", FileMode.Create);
            fsWord.Write(bytesWord, 0, bytesWord.Length);
            fsWord.Close();
            fsWord.Dispose();

            if(dtSolicRel.Count > 0)
            {
               var query = (from qr in dtSolicRel
                             select qr).ToList();
            }


        }
```

tentei fazer nessas linhas o meu update, mas não está dando certo. Não consigo trazer os campos na var query para atualizar:

```
if(dtSolicRel.Count > 0)
{
   var query = (from qr in dtSolicRel
                  select qr).ToList();
}
```

bytesPDF é o binário que deverá ser gravado na tabela. A tabela se chama: `POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO`. O dataset se chama: `dsPlanoMedico` e ele já contém todas as tabelas necessárias(4). Usamos ReportViewer.

Essa aqui é a condição para o update:

```
dtSolicRel.Where(p => p.DT_GERACAO == null && p.BL_RELATORIO == null).First();
```

Não testei ainda. Fiz isso, mas estou com dúvidas de como gravar no BD, pois não tenho contexto e estou uma baita dúvida em como fazer com DataSet.

```
dtSolicRel.Where(p => p.DT_GERACAO == null && p.BL_RELATORIO == null).First();
            if (dtSolicRel.Count > 0 && bytesPDF.Length > 0)
            {
                var query = dtSolicRel.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.DT_GERACAO == null && x.BL_RELATORIO == null).First();

                query.BL_RELATORIO = bytesPDF;
                query.DT_GERACAO = DateTime.Now;
            }
```

EDITADO ABAIXO

Estou fazendo isso e vou testar. O que eu achei estranho é que não aceitou o DateTime.Now(), mas assim: DateTime.Now.

```
var query = dtSolicRel.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.DT_GERACAO == null && x.BL_RELATORIO == null).First();

            query.BL_RELATORIO = bytesPDF;
            query.DT_GERACAO = DateTime.Now;

            solic_adapt.Update(query);
```

Tentei fazer isso, mas está dando erro devido testar null, mas não vejo outra forma.

```
var query = (from i in dtSolicRel
                         //where i.DT_GERACAO == null && i.BL_RELATORIO == null
                         select i).ToList().First();

            if(query.BL_RELATORIO == null && query.DT_GERACAO == null)
            {
                query.BL_RELATORIO = bytesPDF;
                query.DT_GERACAO = DateTime.Now;
                solic_adapt.Update(query);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o linq da seguinte maneira:

```
DataTable dtSolicRel= dataSet.Tables["NomeTabelaa"];

var rowsWithAccount = from row in dtSolicRel.AsEnumerable()
                      where row.Field<object>("DT_GERACAO") == null && row.Field<object>("BL_RELATORIO") == null
                      select row;
```

Para popular campos do dtSolicRel

```
foreach(DataRow row in rowsWithAccount)
{
    row.SetField("DT_GERACAO", DateTime.Now());
    row.SetField("BL_RELATORIO", arquivo);
}
```

Após isso, basta utilizar o DataAdapter para realizar o update no banco.

Comment: Não consigo pegar o dataSets. Para mim DataSets, mas não tem a propriedade Table. Não consigo atribuir nada.

Comment: Não está sendo possível criar isso: DataTable dtSolicRel= dataSet.Tables["NomeTabelaa"]; dtSolicRel já é um datatable e apontando para a tabela correspondente. veja o código postado e veja o que devo fazer. Vou editar o post e mostrar o que eu fiz e minhas dificuldades.

Comment: seu exemplo está ok. Acho que esse é o caminho, só vou agora fazê-lo gravar apenas um registro e sair, pois essa é a regra, não todos os null, apenas o primeiro registro que encontrar, popula e só.

Comment: Desculpa a demora, fico feliz em ajudar... no caso se ja for um datatable, nao precisa da linha DataTable dtSolicRel= dataSet.Tables["NomeTabelaa"]; Voce ja vai direto usando o datatable.